# New to C++ : Unresolved Error

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++ so other posts on this topic were a little too technical for me. I am getting an Unresolved External Symbol Error when I try to compile my code.

Here is my .h file:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Item 
{
private: 
  string description;
  double price;
  int weight;
  int quantity;

public:
 Item(void);
 ~Item(void); 
 Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description);
 void setOrderPrice(double amount);
 void setOrderWeight(int ounces);
 void setDescription(string desc);
 void setQuantity(int number);

 int getOrderPrice();
 int getOrderWeight();
 string getDescription();
 int getQuantity();

 void show();
};
```

This is my .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Item.h"
using namespace std;

Item::Item(void)
{
}


Item::~Item(void)
{
}

void Item::setOrderPrice(double amount) {
 price = amount;
}

void Item::setOrderWeight(int ounces) {
 weight = ounces;
}

void Item::setDescription(string desc) {
 description = desc;
}

void Item::setQuantity(int number) {
 quantity = number;
}

int Item::getOrderPrice() {
 return price;
}

int Item::getOrderWeight() {
 return weight;
}

string Item::getDescription() {
 return description;
}

int Item::getQuantity() {
 return quantity;
}

void Item::show() {
 cout << price << weight << description;
}
```

Finally the file containing my main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Item.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
 double dTotalPrice = 0.0;
 int iTotalWeight = 0;
 Item itmMouse(24.99, 14, "Wireless Mouse");
 Item itmKeyboard(22.49, 27, "USB Keyboard");
 Item itmHDMI (24.99, 12, "HDMI Cable");
 Item itmGlasses(7.99, 7, "Reading Glasses");
 itmGlasses.setQuantity(2);
 // Show the details of the order using printDetails() 
 cout << "Here are your shopping cart contents.\n";
 itmMouse.show();
 itmKeyboard.show();
 itmHDMI.show();
 itmGlasses.show();
 // Compute the total price and total weight in this section
 dTotalPrice += itmMouse.getOrderPrice();
 dTotalPrice += itmKeyboard.getOrderPrice();
 dTotalPrice += itmHDMI.getOrderPrice();
 dTotalPrice += itmGlasses.getOrderWeight();
 iTotalWeight += itmGlasses.getOrderPrice();
 iTotalWeight += itmKeyboard.getOrderWeight();
 iTotalWeight += itmHDMI.getOrderWeight();
 iTotalWeight += itmGlasses.getOrderWeight();
 // Here we show the order details
 cout << "The price of your order is $ " << dTotalPrice << endl;
 cout << "The shipping weight is " << iTotalWeight << " ounces\n";
 cout << "That is " << iTotalWeight / 16 << " pounds\n";

 return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall       Item::Item(double,int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Item@@QAE@NHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Please let me know (in as non-technical of terms as possible) what I am doing wrong and how to fix it. Thank you in advance for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You've defined a constructor in your header that you've not implemented.

Comment: You did not write the function matching the prototype `Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description);`

Comment: If you are very new to C++ then I would advise you to go through a decent  book and online references thoroughly :)

Comment: Pass string desc paramater as const reference (const string& desc) to avoid a copy. Also note it is not neccesary to put void in your parameters if there are none.

Answer (score 8):

As the linker say, you missed in your .cpp file the implementation of the

```
  Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description);
```

so add in the .cpp

```
  Item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description)
  {
   // your initialization step....
  }
```

Comment: I think I did what you suggested correctly. This allowed the compiler to finally work, but I am getting a very strange result, so something is not right.

This is what the compiler shows:

Here are your shopping cart contents.
-9.25596e+061-858993460-9.25596e+061-858993460-9.25596e+061-858993460-9.25596e+0
61-858993460The price of your order is $ -7.30144e+009
The shipping weight is -429496732 ounces
That is -26843545 pounds
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: other problem, other question, and please put your whole code showing how you use that class. for now the value look like non initialized variables!

Comment: This is my .h file:

    '#pragma once
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class Item 
    {
    private: 
 string description;
 double price;
 int weight;
 int quantity;

    public:
 Item(void);
 ~Item(void);
 Item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string   
        Description);
 void setOrderPrice(double amount);
 void setOrderWeight(int ounces);
 void setDescription(string desc);
 void setQuantity(int number);

 int getOrderPrice();
 int getOrderWeight();
 string getDescription();
 int getQuantity();

 void show();
     };'

Comment: This is my .cpp file:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Item.h"
using namespace std;

Item::Item(void)
{
}

Item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description)
{
}

Item::~Item(void)
{
}
void Item::setOrderPrice(double amount) {
 price = amount;
}
void Item::setOrderWeight(int ounces) {
 weight = ounces;
}
void Item::setDescription(string desc) {
 description = desc;
}
void Item::setQuantity(int number) {
 quantity = number;
}
int Item::getOrderPrice() {
 return price;
}
int Item::getOrderWeight() {
 return weight;

Comment: Part 2 of .cpp:


`}
string Item::getDescription() {
 return description;
}
int Item::getQuantity() {
 return quantity;
}
void Item::show() {
 cout << price << weight << description;
}`

Comment: This is my main:

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Item.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
 double dTotalPrice = 0.0;
 int iTotalWeight = 0;
 Item itmMouse(24.99, 14, "Wireless Mouse");
 Item itmKeyboard(22.49, 27, "USB Keyboard");
 Item itmHDMI (24.99, 12, "HDMI Cable");
 Item itmGlasses(7.99, 7, "Reading Glasses");
 itmGlasses.setQuantity(2);
 // Show the details of the order using printDetails() 
 cout << "Here are your shopping cart contents.\n";
 itmMouse.show();
 itmKeyboard.show();
 itmHDMI.show();
 itmGlasses.show();

Comment: This is main part 2: 

// Compute the total price and total weight in this section
 dTotalPrice += itmMouse.getOrderPrice();
 dTotalPrice += itmKeyboard.getOrderPrice();
 dTotalPrice += itmHDMI.getOrderPrice();
 dTotalPrice += itmGlasses.getOrderWeight();
 iTotalWeight += itmGlasses.getOrderPrice();
 iTotalWeight += itmKeyboard.getOrderWeight();
 iTotalWeight += itmHDMI.getOrderWeight();
 iTotalWeight += itmGlasses.getOrderWeight();

Comment: Main part 3:

 // Here we show the order details
 cout << "The price of your order is $ " << dTotalPrice << endl;
 cout << "The shipping weight is " << iTotalWeight << " ounces\n";
 cout << "That is " << iTotalWeight / 16 << " pounds\n";
 
 return 0;

}

Comment: @David, I'm sorry but open new question and put your last version of item implementation to show your constructor.

Comment: this is the URL for the new question I asked. Thank you for your help. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929923/code-compiling-strangely)

Answer (score 0):

Provide the parameterized constructor for the Item class as the compiler can only provide a default constructor(Item()), And you have to provide the parameterized if u need to create objects with default values as you did in your main.cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

you never actually define the overloaded constructor that you declare in Itme.h

unresolved external means that it could not resolve or in other words find the function that you call or declare

external means it should be defined somewhere in another .obj file 
sense Visual Studio compiles every .cpp file in to different .obj files
and then links them together and sense you tell it that there is a function 
called Item::Item... there should be one but there isn't this is easy if the 
source file is written by you and its part of the project it would be a lot 
harder if it was in a library witch would mean that you have not linked the 
right libraries (Just so you know because you will encounter this as everybody does  )

to solve this just add the function definition in Item.cpp

```
     Item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description)
     {
     }
```