# Code Compiling Strangely

Tags: c++

I think that I was reasonably able to fix my code so it would compile, but something is still off about it.

This is my .h file

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Item 
{
private: 
 string description;
 double price;
 int weight;
 int quantity;

public:
 Item(void);
 ~Item(void);
 Item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description);
 void setOrderPrice(double amount);
 void setOrderWeight(int ounces);
 void setDescription(string desc);
 void setQuantity(int number);

 int getOrderPrice();
 int getOrderWeight();
 string getDescription();
 int getQuantity();

 void show();
 };
```

This is my .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Item.h"
using namespace std;

Item::Item(void)
{
}

Item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description)
{
}

Item::~Item(void)
{
}

void Item::setOrderPrice(double amount) {
 price = amount;
}

void Item::setOrderWeight(int ounces) {
 weight = ounces;
}

void Item::setDescription(string desc) {
 description = desc;
}

void Item::setQuantity(int number) {
 quantity = number;
}

int Item::getOrderPrice() {
 return price;
}

 int Item::getOrderWeight() {
 return weight;
 }

 string Item::getDescription() {
 return description;
 }

 int Item::getQuantity() {
 return quantity;
 }

 void Item::show() {
 cout << price << weight << description;
 }
```

This is my main file:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include "Item.h"
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
double dTotalPrice = 0.0;
int iTotalWeight = 0;
Item itmMouse(24.99, 14, "Wireless Mouse");
Item itmKeyboard(22.49, 27, "USB Keyboard");
Item itmHDMI (24.99, 12, "HDMI Cable");
Item itmGlasses(7.99, 7, "Reading Glasses");
itmGlasses.setQuantity(2);
// Show the details of the order using printDetails() 
cout << "Here are your shopping cart contents.\n";
itmMouse.show();
itmKeyboard.show();
itmHDMI.show();
itmGlasses.show();
// Compute the total price and total weight in this section
dTotalPrice += itmMouse.getOrderPrice();
dTotalPrice += itmKeyboard.getOrderPrice();
dTotalPrice += itmHDMI.getOrderPrice();
dTotalPrice += itmGlasses.getOrderWeight();
iTotalWeight += itmGlasses.getOrderPrice();
iTotalWeight += itmKeyboard.getOrderWeight();
iTotalWeight += itmHDMI.getOrderWeight();
iTotalWeight += itmGlasses.getOrderWeight();
// Here we show the order details
cout << "The price of your order is $ " << dTotalPrice << endl;
cout << "The shipping weight is " << iTotalWeight << " ounces\n";
cout << "That is " << iTotalWeight / 16 << " pounds\n";

return 0;

 }
```

I am interested in knowing where I went wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what's "off" about it?

Comment: You obviously went wrong when you didn't provide what error message you get...

Comment: It's compiling with strange numbers instead of values resembling what I should be getting.

Comment: Getting your code to compile is step #1.  Getting the *logic* right is, well, often more difficult.

Answer (score 4):

In your .h file:

```
Item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description);
```

Should be :

```
Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description);
```

No need to qualify the second constructor.

Also note:

```
int Item::getOrderPrice() {
  return price;
}
```

Price is a `double` and you are returning an `int`.  Finally:

```
iTotalWeight += itmGlasses.getOrderPrice();
```

You are adding a "Price" to your "Weight" - probably not what you wanted.

Last, you are not storing your values from your item() constructor in any of your vars.  use an initializer list in your item.cpp file constructor:

```
Item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description):
    description(Description),
    price(OrderPrice),
    weight(OrderWeight),
    quantity(1)
...
```

Compiler warnings/errors flagged all these issues for me...

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to tell us what went wrong. Maybe you get a compile error, since (in the class definition) the constructor declaration

```
Item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description);
```

should just be

```
Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description);
```

Or perhaps it compiles for you (since some compilers accept that error), but you get strange results. This is because that constructor doesn't initialise the members, so they have garbage values. Perhaps you want:

```
Item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description) :
    description(Description),
    price(OrderPrice),
    weight(OrderWeight),
    quantity(1)
{}
```

It might also be a good idea to remove the default constructor, so that users can't accidentally create an uninitialised object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your constructor doesn't initialize class member

```
   Item::Item() : description(""), price(0), weight(0), quantity(0)
   {}

   item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description) :
    description(Description),
    price(OrderPrice),
    .... etc....
     {}
```

So all your call to the "getter " will return uninitialized values.

Answer (score 0):

To get good results on stack overflow, and to help yourself learn, a key step is to create small reproducible test cases that clearly state what you expect, and what you are getting.

Let's reduce your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

class Item
{
    private:
        string description;
        double price;
        int weight;
        int quantity;

    public:
        Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description);
        int getOrderPrice();
};

Item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description)
{
}

int Item::getOrderPrice() {
    return price;
}

int main() {
    Item itmMouse(24.99, 14, "Wireless Mouse");
    assert(itmMouse.getOrderPrice() == 24.99);
}
```

Now, for anyone looking at this code, (and you should include a note about this as well), it's clear that the confusion is that your price is wrong. And at this point, we can clearly say that the issue is that your constructor does not copy it's arguments to the class members.

A potential fix would be a constructor that looks like:

```
Item::Item(double OrderPrice, int OrderWeight, string Description)
{
    price = OrderPrice;
    weight = OrderWeight;
    description = Description;
    quantity = 1;
}
```

*Instead of the assert that I'm using, we could also just look at the output of `Item::show()`. That line is the first point in your original code where something comes out that is not what you expect. That's where I started when I reduced your code.*